# Virtual Switch High Network Receive Traffic When Idle

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v, switch

Having an issue where my network adapter is constantly showing relatively high Receive traffic when system is completely idle.

This happens after Hyper-V creates an external Virtual Switch.

Is this normal? Any way to fix this?

**Environment & additional details:**

- Windows Server 2019, latest SP/update as of now
- Mellanox ConnectX-2 10GBE Network Adapter, single port, no NIC teaming
- Receive traffic always hovers ~17Mbps, if Virtual Switch is removed it goes to 0Mbps
- I experienced an identical issue with this NIC model on Unraid OS, issue was fixed by disabling both Bridging and Bonding network settings (not related to virtual switch)
- Issue is reproducible on other machines with same hardware

Comment: Without the bridge. your interface will drop all traffic not destined to your host, but a bridge will bridge all unknown unicast, broadcast, and multicast traffic on the broadcast domain. That is the point of a bridge. If you want to separate that traffic, you need to use a different network and route between networks. Also, I would look at braking up a broadcast domain ( on the network external to your host) with that much background traffic.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, the details make it easy to understand. The thing is I am not using a bridge. Is the bridge somehow is used or created internally when you create Hyper-V Virtual Switch?